# Python Field Calculation

Tags: python, arcmap, field-calculator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterative position within Field Calculator/Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22751/iterative-position-within-field-calculator-python)

I need to calculate a field for a data set that is grouped by county. At each change in county I need the column to start from 1 and progress up until the end of the county group and then start over.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail? i.e. version, and maybe a screenshot of the dbf?

Comment: Please be more descriptive -- I don't follow the "at each change in county I need the column to start from 1 and progress..."

Comment: So I have a large set of grids that overlay each county and there is a column named 'County' with the name of that county. There is a column named 'Tile' that needs to start at the integer '1' and each new grid would progress by +1 until the end of the county group. Then the next county group would start over at '1' and progress by +1.

Comment: This is very similar to this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22751/iterative-position-within-field-calculator-python

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that. I looked and must have passed over this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python in the field calculator is really best for very simple operations.  Any time you have to change values based on a field, it gets a bit too complicated for my liking.  You might want to script it instead using **cursors**